# Comparing a variable to a range of numbers in BASH

Tags: bash

How would one go about comparing a variable, lets say

Var1

to a range of numbers such as 0-5. If Var1 is in that range then the statement will return true, else will print an error or exit.

Comment: How are you being given this range?

Comment: Var1 will be given through stdin, basically if the user doesnt input 1,2,3,4 or 5 through stdin then it will just print an error

Comment: So just test if it's greater than 0 and less than 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms, you can just test the variable passed while running the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if (( 0 <= $1 && $1 <= 5 )); then
    echo "In range"
else
    echo "Not in range"
fi
```

Pass the number to the script and it will test it against your range. For example, if the above it put in a script called `check.sh` then:

```
$ bash check.sh 10
Not in range
$ bash check.sh 3
In range
```

You can make the script executable to avoid using `bash ...` whenever you need to run the script. The `$1` used above the is the first parameter passed to the script. If you don't like to use positional variables, then you can save it a variable inside the script if you wish.

Comment: +1. Purely as a matter of style, I write `(( 0 <= $1 && $1 <= 5 ))` -- that's closest to math notation `a ≤ x ≤ b`

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman. Actually, I like that style. Will use that from now on. Makes it more readable too. Thank you. Will update.